# Which formula of p(x, y) to use?

Tags: generative-model, books, probability-theory

The probability distribution $p(x, y)$ can be calculated in two ways :

1. $p(x, y) = p(y \mid x) p(x)$
2. $p(x, y) = p(x \mid y) p(y)$

But according to the book [Deep Generative Modeling](https://books.google.com.np/books/about/Deep_Generative_Modeling.html?id=uidgEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page number 3 first paragraph last line) (1) has clear advantages that (2). Why?

Answer (score 2):

In the book you mentioned, the author is dealing with classification, that is, inferring the label $y$ from a sample $x$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the corresponding random variables. $p(y|x)$ can be understood as $P(Y=y|X=x)$, that is, the probability of class $y$ given that we observed sample $x$. Therefore, **for classification**, considering $p(x, y) = p(y|x)p(x)$ is **more natural** than otherwise.